# Need this vue-router function translated to ecma script 2015

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js

I dont get the following function translated to ecmascript 2015

```
  route: {
        data: function () {
            return this.$http.get('/api/posts?sort=title&order=1').then(
                    posts=>{this.table.posts = posts.data}
            );
        }
    },
```

<s>because `this` isnt refering to the window object</s> I get the

```
[vue-router] Uncaught error during transition: be.js:3660:7

TypeError: undefined has no properties[Learn More]be.js:16572:13
```

Comment: Why do you expect this to refer to the window object? You wrote `because this isnt refering to the window object I get the`.

Comment: I dont say I excpect it to refer to the window object, I just want to use the function this.http, Let me edit it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question. Does your non-ES2015 code work so far, and you're trying to port it to ES2015? Or do you think you need to convert it to ES2015 in order for it to work?

Comment: It works , I just need it in es2015

Comment: Not so relative to the question, but you are not supposed to make any ajax call into your data property. You should initialize your data as an ampty array in `data()` and then make your ajax call into the `created()` hook. In the Ajax callback, you then update your component `data()` from the response

Comment: @El_Matella are you talking about the vue `data()` hook, or the vue router `data()` hook?

Comment: I need to make the ajax call at the Data hook because Im expecting the $loadingRouteData to work.

Comment: Ho yes @nils I was completely off topic, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use certain features such as [shorthand method names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) and slightly more compact arrow functions to make it looks more ES2015, but it won't change the functionality:

```
route: {
    data() {
        return this.$http
            .get('/api/posts?sort=title&order=1')
            .then(posts => { this.table.posts = posts.data });
    }
},
```

You couldn't replace the `data` hook function with an arrow functions, because `this` would refer to the wrong context (either to `window` or `undefined`), as its `this` would be defined by its surrounding lexical scope and could not be overriden.

Comment: Thank you . I need to Read more.

Comment: If I use the soultion as It . it Gives me the vm.instance initialization Error. so I had to enclose it with posts => {this.table.posts = posts.data}